# ..can stop the equipment work/working/from working?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I've just returned from an English exam and there was a sentence that made me wonder (I'm not exactly sure about the wording). The sentence ran like this :

> Overheating can stop the equipment FUNCTION/TO FUNCTION/FROM
>   FUNCTIONING/FUNCTIONING

Which is the correct one and why? Thank you.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-as-a-second-language?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2

Comment: @Robusto: I hate this proposal SO much. It's like opening a stackoverflow for beginners. Not fair, really. :(

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Well, perhaps we need a stackoverflow for beginners.

Comment: @Robusto: I don't think we do. It's fine as it is, the stackoverflow Q&A, as is this ELU Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is *from functioning*.

> The overheating can stop the equi**pm**ent from functioning.

"To stop something from doing something" means "to prevent" or "to restrain" (see meaning 6 [in this dictionary entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stop)).

If *the equipment* were the subject, you wouldn't need *from*, and the word *stop* would mean *cease*

> The equipment may stop <s>from</s> functioning from overheating.

Comment: [That link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stop) allows "... from functioning"  but does not seem to rule out "Overheating can stop the equipment functioning" (see sense 7).

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7 - Agreed. The only thing that could make that incorrect (and absolutely require *from*) is changing *the* to *this* (equipment).